# Magento 2: Alternative solution to large number of values inside 1 attribute

Tags: magento2.3, php, attributes, product-attribute

We have Product Attribute called "Authors" with "Multiselect option". It has entries up to 51k. When we edit product page in backend it becomes very slow to load page and specially this attribute with values inside it. Now we have another 400k authors with products to import and i am expecting its not good to load all values inside 1 product author attribute, it can crash or slow down the whole website.

```
Attribute code: authors
Attribute label: Authors
Catalog Input Type for Store Owner: Multi select
```

Any suggestion would be great on that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed an exceptional scenario and you should consider some optimizations. In time the list will grow only larger, as you already mentioned.

On a quick thinking on the matter, here is what I suggest: you could group the products in different attribute sets and **use a specific author attribute per attribute set**.

I don't know what type of products you are selling, but you could group items of similar genre or type into the same attribute set. You can add a 'generic/ default' attribute set and reuse that to generate subsequent attribute sets in which the difference is that they use a different attribute for author specification. See below the new attribute set form where you have to mention which is the attribute set you will use as base:

[image]